# "Twice in" ? can preposition be used after twice?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which is the correct sentence:

- He goes to museum twice a week
- He goes to museum twice in a week

Comment: Not many of the 'go to' expressions are used without the definite article; 'go to school' / 'work' / 'hospital' (BrE), when used in the non-geographical senses, are some. As is 'go to bed'.

Answer (score 1):

1. He goes to the museum twice a week.
2. He goes to the museum twice in a week.

The first implies that he goes twice every week. The second states that in one given week, he went twice.

Comment: Yes; it would be unusual to meet the second example in the present tense (without padding: 'For years, he never shows an interest in culture, and then he goes to the museum twice in a week!')

Comment: Thanks Edwin and KillingTime. It really cleared out all doubts. It makes sense. :)

Comment: 'He goes to the museum' and 'He went to the museum' are different, as your last sentence shows.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is, **"He goes to *the* museum twice a week."** (Note the word "museum" requires an article before it in your example.) It answers the implied question, "How often does he go to the museum?" Answer: "Twice a week."

There is nothing inherently wrong with "twice in." For example, if you were emphasizing the **frequency** of his trips, you might say, **"He went to the museum twice in one day."** In that case, you are choosing to emphasize the frequency as **unusual**. If you were simply **stating a fact**, you would say, **"He went to the museum twice a day."** That is, he made it a regular (ordinary) habit of visiting the museum twice a day.